# I am having problems with removing tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have a problem with the fact that I can't get the widgets of my screen. I have tried to use `(widget).forget()` but it doesn't work? Can someone help?

Comment: What geometry manager are you using? There is .pack, .grid. and .place. If you are using .grid you have to use .grid_forget().

Comment: im using.place()

Comment: I tried place_forget() but it didn't work

Comment: Typically using the place manager isn't recommenced since if anything changes then it can throw off other widgets causing you to have to re-place everything. I thought place_forget should work. It may be helpful for you to post a snippet of code to see if the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah ok but im not home right now i'll post it when i Come home

Comment: As you question is currently written it's unclear how we can assist you. To make an analogy, you have essentially stated "I have a problem with my car, I tried using a wrench but it didn't work. Can someone help?" Without knowing what the problem is or even what kind of car you have, how can we be expected to provide anything that will actually help you?

Comment: first: you should run code in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if you don't get error message. Second: you should put in question minimal working code which we could run and see your problem. If you get error message then you should also add it in question. Currently we can't help you.

Comment: `place_forget` will work if you're using place. If it's not, then please show a [mcve] to illustrate what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you code got a little jumbled when you posted it. It looks like the problem is you created the button and placed it in one action. The pack/place/grid function returns None so "knapp1" is not assigned to the button. What you want to do is create the button and assign it to the knapp1 varaible then pack/place/grid on a new line.

Also if you weren't aware you can't mix the grid and pack managers.

And once you get more comfortable look into using classes when making UIs. It makes it much easier to reference stuff on your UI and call functions.

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

bilde1 = PhotoImage(file='untitled.png') 
bilde2 = PhotoImage(file='ikke navngitt.png')

def but1(): 
    knapp1.place_forget()

label1 = Label(root, image=bilde1).pack() 
knapp1 = Button(root, image=bilde2,command=but1)
knapp1.place(x=0,y=3)

root.mainloop()
```